Laptop locks screen automatically whenever i connect the MX keys keyboard
The initial days of purchase of mx keys worked fine. That is around 1 year. Now, whenever i connect my mx keys keyboard to laptop (tried with other laptops) the screen locks
automatically and one of the keys is being pressed and it shows in the password section. it continuous until i press backspace and clear all the entries in the password section. if i clear everything and enter password, i can use the the system and after a while the screen locks automatically this time no key is being pressed, its like we press win+L on keyboard. Then again if i unlock and use the same locking thing happens repeatedly without any key being pressed. like win+L.
i tried resetting the keyboard multiple times and not resolved
my laptop is hp notebook , i also tried with dell one and same issue happens

Are you sure you're using known good batteries? If so your keyboard is defective. Activate the warranty if applicable or replace it.
